# Need help installing Frisch in Ubuntu via APT

Tags: apt

I am trying to install a program in Ubuntu following a guide:

> **Installation through APT**
>
> There are several ways to install the software. For Ubuntu users with
>   an internet connection the simplest is as follows.
>
> Create a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/frisch.list containing the line
>
> ```
> deb http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu main
> ```
>
> (where you should substitute with your distribution, hardy, jaunty,
>   karmic, lucid etc)

**How do I create that `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/frisch.list` file?**

Comment: Can you share the link of the instructions you are following?

Comment: that page is rather old (@M.Becerra you can click the link in the post (until I broke it...)) - I am not sure this software will work (last updated 2015)...

Comment: You can read about what a distribution is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution

Comment: These instructions are from http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu/.

Comment: What programm is Frish?

Comment: there are several ways to make this file. Either from terminal or from GUI. Just you need to have root access to make any change there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to install software on Ubuntu, and this method involves adding a repository to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory so that when you run `sudo apt-get update` your repository list will be updated as well to include software from that added repository.

Now the line to add is this:

```
deb http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu <dist> main
```

To get your *dist* which stands for *distribution*, run `lsb_release -a` in the terminal and you should see this:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial     <---- dist
```

Hence the line above would be: `deb http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu xenial main`

Now to create that file we can use any text editor but I recommend `nano` which you use like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/frisch.list
```

Inside that file enter the following line:

```
deb http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu xenial main
```

Then use the following to save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Now to install the software included in that repository we will:

1. Add the key to verify installs from that repo:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 502199FA
   ```
2. Then update and install `frisch`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install frisch
   ```
3. Then to upgrade it in the future do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

**NOTE:**

As Zanna had stated in a comment the page is rather **old**. These are the steps that you would follow in installing that application in your system now.

Comment: Hi George, thank you very much for the answer. When I try to save the file in Nano (pressing ctrl+o) and hit enter, I get the message "[ Error writing /etc/apt/source.list.d/frisch.list: No such file or directory ]".

Comment: @STATEN_star the name should be /etc/apt/source**s**.list.d/frisch.list

Comment: Thanks  @steeldriver, STATEN_star sorry it should be `sources.list` not `source.list` typo error

Answer (score 1):

The text in the original instructions should have been something like:

```
deb http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu <dist> main
```

You must replace `<dist>` with the corresponding name of the distribution you want to install. A list of the distribution archives can be found here:
    http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu/dists/

However, the distribution should also match the release name of your Ubuntu distribution. That list can be found here: 
    https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames

Now, if you compare the two lists you will see that the software you want to install is rather old. As such I'm in doubt it will be supported in any way. The newest release available is "raring". This corresponds to Ubuntu 13.04 which reached End of Life back in January 2014.

If you have any newer release you can try to follow the instructions and add the following line to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/frisch.list file:

```
deb http://folk.uio.no/sgaure/ubuntu <dist> main
```

You can create the file from a terminal window using:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/frisch.list
```

If you are lucky it might work. However, things are really outdated and on a newer Ubuntu distribution you will get at least a security warning due to the weak SHA1 digest algorithm during the upgrade process.